# can't find variable in <%=%>

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I added a new web form in asp.net application which named Home. 
In `Home.aspx.cs` I used these following codes :

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string str = "Hello and welcome to c#";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Then I go to `Home.aspx` but unfortunately It won't find `str` variable.

These are the codes in `Home.aspx` :

```
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%=str %>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you post the class mentioned in the `Page` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's a problem with asp.net error. Because it shows me error but when I start without debugging it show me the string and won't show any error after that.

By the way there's no problem with protected.

Comment: @AbdelOlakara The name 'str' does not exist in the current context

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. Anyways, are saying that the problem only happens in debug mode?

Answer (score -2):

your `str` variable should be `public` not `protected`, use like:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string str = "Hello and welcome to c#";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: -1: Nonsensical. Protected members are available in derived classes.

Comment: @leppie it can be also private as well because both .aspx and .aspx.cs are partial class am I right?

Comment: @krshekhar: No, the aspx page always derives from the codebehind class.